# Flutter Auth0 Web Authentication shows blank page

Tags: flutter, authentication, auth0

I am trying to get Auth0 to work within my Flutter Mobile application.

When I press the login button it takes me to a blank webpage where the login screen would be. Based on the documents that Auth0 provide I have it setup correctly.

Has anyone had this problem and has a solution?

I will add some images and some code to this post.

```
onPressed: () async {
   final auth0 = Auth0("DOMAIN",
   "CLIENT_ID");
   final result = await auth0.webAuthentication(scheme:
   "DOMAIN/android/com.example.name/login")
   .login(redirectUrl: "com.example.name://login");
   final accessToken = result.accessToken;
}
```

Buildgradle

```
manifestPlaceholders += [auth0Domain: "DOMAIN", auth0Scheme: "https"]
```

[image: Advanced Settings]

[image]

Hopefully I get some answers.

Cheers Devs

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is over a year old, but I've seen the same thing in several places and I seem to have found an answer.

Either use API 32 or lower, or in API 33 and higher sign in to a google account and update your browser.

I've had the same problem - my physical phones always launched the Auth0 webview correctly, while emulators always showed a blank page, or in case of Firefox, they showed a redirection error.

The issue seems to be related with Auth0 safety or redirection handling.